# How did Euler calculate his $\gamma$ constant to 16 digits?

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

I couldn't find any information online on how Euler calculated this to 16 digits of accuracy:
$$
\gamma = - \ln{n} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k
$$
Obviously not like that, can somebody help please?

Comment: Euler calculated his $\gamma$ constant upto $16$ digits as he was **Euler**

Comment: It could have been through series acceleration, but I imagine he numerically evaluated [an integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Integrals). By the way, this question would be a good fit for the [HSM Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, didn't know it existed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some googling turns up [this paper](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gamma.pdf) in which the authors claim that Euler did this computation using [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

$$H_n - \log n \approx \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{B_{2k}}{2k} \frac{1}{n^{2k}}$$

where $B_{2k}$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Specifically the authors claim Euler went up to the $k = 6$ term of this expansion and calculated everything to $16$ digits of accuracy for $n = 10$.

Comment: Ah, so it was [series acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) (I meant to include that link in my other comment) after all. +1.